# Gradle publish Android library: no action

Tags: gradle, publish, android-library

Gradle publish Android lib AAR:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'


publishing {
    publications {
        androidLib(MavenPublication) {
            group 'com.example'
            artifactId 'foo'
            version '1.0'
            artifact bundleDebug
        }
    }
}
```

publish:

```
gradle publish
```

Error: skip task 'publish' as it has no action